# How to load images after the window is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

My website has tons of large images that reduces my site speed. I want to load all of the images of my website after the website is loaded without them.

What is the best solution to do that??? I want it in jQuery. Any NICE JQUERY PLUGIN suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean that you want to run javascript before all the images are finished loading, or do you want to asynchronously load images after the rest of the page contents have finished rendering?

Comment: @zzzzBov - I want to load the images after the rest of the page contents have finished rendering.

Comment: What you really SHOULD do is try to eliminate those large images. You're trying to concoct a code-based solution for a design-based problem, and there's no perfect fix for that. Use thumbnail images that link to the larger image. Or save your images at a higher JPEG compression. Or, better yet, both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My favorite is http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: @sbom - Thanks for your answer. But lazyload seems doesn't work on my site :( FYI, I cannot use data-original attr for the images. Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this on my ASP pages.

Just create all your images tags like this

```
<img ID="img_1"/>
```

Once this is done, with Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        document.img_1.src="YourImageUrl";
});
```

There you go, as soon as your page is done loading the content, it will show all your images.

Comment: This will still reduce your page loading times (if checking with Google page speed). You want to add it to window onload event instead